# Show that $j(X)$ is closed in $X^{**}$ where $j:X \rightarrow X^{**}$ is a natural embedding

Tags: functional-analysis, isometry

The following problem can be obtained in the book 'An Introductory Course in Functional Analysis' by Bowers and Kalton, page $59$, problem $3.5$

Known facts about $j$: It is a linear, injection and isometry map.

> Question: Let $X$ be a Banach space with bidual $X^{**}$ and let $j:X
>  \rightarrow X^{**}$ be the natural embedding.  Show that $j(X)$ is a
>   closed subset of $X^{**}.$

My attempt: I wish to prove that $j(X)$ is sequantially closed.

Suppose that a sequence $(x^{**}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $j(X)$ converges to $x^{**}$.

Since $j$ is injective, there exists a unique $x_n \in X$ such that $j(x_n) = x_n^{**}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$

**I am having trouble to show that the sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in $X.$** If it does converge, say converge to $x$, then by continuity of $j,$ we have $(x_n^{**})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $j(x)$, which is equal to $x^{**}.$

By the way, authors suggest that since $j$ is isometry, therefore we have $j(X)$ is closed in $X^{**}.$ But I don't see it.

UPDATE: The following is my full proof to the question. Is it correct?

We wish to show that $j(X)$ is sequentially closed in $X^{**}.$
        Let $(x_n^{**})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $j(X)$ that converges to $x^{**}.$ 
        We wish to show that $x^{**} \in j(X).$
        By injectivity of $j,$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N},$ there exists a unique element $x_n \in X$ such that $j(x_n) = x_n^{**}.$
        Recall that any convergent sequence is Cauchy. 
        In particular, $(x_n^{**})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $j(X).$
        Since $j$ is an isometry, we have $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy in $X.$
        Since $X$ is a Banach space, $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $x \in X.$
        As $j$ is continuous, we have $(x_n^{**})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $j(x).$
        By uniqueness of limit, we have $j(x) = x^{**}.$ 
        Hence, $x^{**} \in j(X).$

Comment: You need that $X$ is a Banach space, otherwise $j(X)$ is not closed. On the other hand, since $j$ is an isometry and $X$ is complete $j(X)$ is a complete subspace of $X^{**}$, thus closed. If you want to continue your proof, use that $j$ is an isometry to find that $x_n$ is a Cauchy Sequence, thus must converge to some value $x$ if $X$ is complete. Then you see with continuity that $j(x_n)$ converges to $j(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$J(X)$ is an isometric embbeding of $X$ in $X^{**}$ thus because of the fact that $X$ is complete then $J(X)$ is also a complete subset of $X^{**}$ and also $X^{**}$ is a banach space thus $J(X)$ is closed.

In general ,remember that a complete subset of a complete space is closed.